# I cannot iterate a xml file in jenkins pipeline

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to understand how to iterate a .xml file in Jenkins so I create a super simple .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tag1>
  <tag2>hello</tag2>
  <tag3>bye</tag3>
</tag1>
```

I just want to get acces to a tag value (i.e. tag3) and print it out. I have been reading a lot here on SO and I this is the cod I have:

```
import groovy.xml.*

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('find') {
            steps {
                script{
                    def xml = readFile "C:\\Users\\anton\\Desktop\\test.xml"
                    def file = new XmlSlurper().parseTest(xml)
                    
                    file.'**'.
                        findAll { it.name() == 'tag1' }
                        .each {println it.assetId.text()}
                }
            }
             
        }
    }
}
```

But I keep getting this error: `hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: groovy.util.XmlSlurper.parseTest() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ï»¿<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
If I try to use XmlParser() method I get the same error too. I have followe these links [java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027382/java-net-malformedurlexception-no-protocol-xml) and it seems to work fine for him I do not find further information from that error

If I delete the last 3 lines then I get this error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Which I do not understand as the xml herader seems fine...

Comment: Assuming that https://stackoverflow.com/a/67390162/4657412 is correct - I've voted to close as a typo

Answer (score 0):

You must approve the use of certain scripts. You can approve them at:

```
yourserver:8080/scriptApproval/
```

Answer (score 0):

parse**Test**(xml) => parse**Text**(xml)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: In this case I think the extra context is "it's a typo; the question should be closed because it has no long-term value"